# Get filtered Networkx MultiDiGraph to behave like a DiGraph

Tags: python, networkx

I have a MultiDiGraph with all my data in it, now I want to do some math on a filtered view of it that has only single directed edges between nodes.

```
>>> filtered_view[0][1]
Out[23]: AtlasView(FilterAtlas({0: {'d': 0.038, 'l': 2, 'showfl': True, 'type': 'pipe', 'q': 0.0001}}, <function FilterMultiInner.__getitem__.<locals>.new_node_ok at 0x7fa0987b55a0>))
```

I already have a lot of code that was working on a DiGraph, so a lot of it would not work anymore because of the differences in accessing and storing information. So thus my question:

Is there a way to have the view behave like a DiGraph?

Alternatively, I can do: `ndg = nx.DiGraph(filtered_view)`to get a DiGraph, but is there a smart (simple, clear, error free) way of merging it back into the main graph?

Comment: What do you need to merge back into the main graph?  If all you need is a `DiGraph` based on the `MultiDiGraph` but without duplicate edges, just do `nx.DiGraph(multidigraphname.edges())`.  Duplicate edges will be removed since `DiGraph` doesn't support them.  Or is there some other info that you need retained in the `DiGraph` that would be stripped if you did that?

Comment: Yes, say i have two edges from node 1 to 2. I use the filter to get the edge that i need (it could be index 0 or index 1 edge, lets say its 1). Now I calculate some value for edge 1, and to feed that calculation I can use `nx.DiGraph(filtered_view)` to create a DiGraph. But after the calc, the result should go back in my MultiDiGraph because I will need edge 0 as well.

Comment: Do you just want to update some information on the edges (and nodes) or manipulate the edges and nodes themselfes?

Comment: Just update information.

Comment: Do the values for edge with index 0 and edge with index 1 need to be unique? For example, let's say you have edge `[A, B, 0]` and edge `[A, B, 1]` between nodes `A` and `B` in your `MultiDiGraph`.  You've already said you can pull the individual edge by index and run a calculation on it.  If you know what `A`, `B`, and the index are, can you not just assign the value from your calculation directly using `G.edges[A, B, index]['attribute'] = value_from_calculation`?  An example of what you're trying to do with some edge names, attributes, and expected results would be super helpful!

Comment: Yes that is correct, I could just do that. However its a lot of code and accessing the edges in a `MultiDiGraph` is just a bit more cumbersome, so I like the idea of working on a simple graph that can only have one edge. I'll post my code below, open for improvements!

Answer (score 0):

This is the implementation I came up with, it allows to either merge only data on existing nodes and edges (`allnodes=False`) or to merge the entire `results_graph` which is a `DiGraph` (`allnodes=True`). Condition is that the `MultiDiGraph` has not changed since the filtered view was created.

```
def merge_results_back(results_graph, multidigraph, allnodes=False):
    for n in results_graph.nodes:
        if n not in multidigraph.nodes and allnodes:
            multidigraph.add_node(n)
        if n in multidigraph.nodes:
            nx.set_node_attributes(multidigraph, {n : results_graph.nodes[n]})
    for e in results_graph.edges:
        if e in multidigraph.edges:
            for ed1, ed2, key, data in multidigraph.edges(e[0], keys=True, data=True):
                if data['type'] == results_graph.edges[e]['type']:
                    nx.set_edge_attributes(multidigraph, {(e[0], e[1], key) : results_graph.edges[e]})
        else:
            nx.set_edge_attributes(multidigraph, {(e[0], e[1], 0): results_graph.edges[e]})
```

Answer (score 0):

Offering a couple of suggestions for improvement here based on the code that you posted.  It's unclear under what circumstances a node would be added (if the `DiGraph` is based on the `MultiDiGraph`, how is a new node possible?), so I'll leave that part alone.

In the loop for modifying edges, you end up looping through `multidigraph` every time a common edge is found.  As an improvement, I'd suggest the following (assuming the `type` attribute differs based on the edge index, which wasn't clear in your question):

```
for u, v, data in results_graph.edges(data = True):
    #only loops through each edge in the multidigraph one time
    for i in range(multidigraph.number_of_edges(u, v)):
        if multidigraph.edges[u, v, i]['type'] == data['type']:
            multidigraph.edges[u, v, i].update(data)
```

If the `type` doesn't change based on the index, just eliminate that `if` statement line.

---

I think you can also get rid of the else block:

```
else:
    nx.set_edge_attributes(multidigraph, {(e[0], e[1], 0): results_graph.edges[e]})
```

If edge `e` from `results_graph` isn't in `multidigraph`, then setting the edge attributes won't create edge `e` and it will be silently ignored.  If you have a new edge and attributes though (again, unclear how this is possible if `results_graph` was created from `multidigraph`), you can add the following directly under the `for u, v, data...` line:

```
if (u, v) not in multidigraph.edges:
    multidigraph.add_edge(u, v, **data)
```